# Catch event in view from another class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift2

I have async task with request where i fetching products every 3 seconds in class `Item`.

```
class Item: NSManagedObject {
    var is_fetching:Bool = false;

    func fetchProducts(q: String) {
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
              (data, response, error) in
              self.is_fetching = true;
              //some code

              if ((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode == 202) {
                  sleep(3)
                  self.fetchProducts(q)
                  return
              }
              if ((response as! NSHTTPURLResponse).statusCode == 200) {
                  self.is_fetching = false;
              }
          })
          task.resume()
      }
}
```

And i have `UITableViewController` where i show data from response. How do i update my cells when status code is 200:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:
        indexPath) as! CartTableViewCell
    if item.is_fetching {
        cell.fetchIndicator.startAnimating();
    } else {
        cell.fetchIndicator.stopAnimating();
        cell.fetchIndicator.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in few ways.

**NSNotificationCenter** (simplest).

You can post notifications, that will trigger your controller's methods. Looks like this:

```
// if response.code == 200
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("kSomeConstatnString", object: nil)
...
// in viewDidLoad of your controller:
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "updateTable", object: nil)
// you also need implement updateTable() func inside your controller
// or if you need just update table
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self.tableView, selector: "reloadData", object: nil)
// do not forget to delete observer (for instance in -deinit method)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self) 
// or tableView. also you can specify for which selector, if you use couple of them.
```

**Delegate pattern.**

You can describe your protocol, make your controller implement this protocol and save it as instance in your model object. Then just call methods from delegate. Details [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/design-patterns-delegation--cms-23901).

**Block callbacks.**

Create block for action and call it from your model. For example:

```
// inside controller
model.refreshCallback = { Void in
  self.tableView.reloadData() // or whatever
}
// inside model
var refreshCallback: (() -> Void)?
...
// if result.code == 200
if let callback = refreshCallback {
  callback()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the `UITableView`’s reload functions, perhaps:

```
func reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_ indexPaths: [NSIndexPath],
           withRowAnimation animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)
```

This will cause it to ask again for the cell in question. Make sure you do this on the main thread.

Comment: but how get UITableView reload function at Item class ?

Comment: That's something you'll have to work out, based on the structure of your app. Perhaps set up a delegate in Item that you can call a method on when the fetch has complete. Or have a variable referring to the table view in your AppDelegate subclass.

Comment: try to use fetchresultcontroller , which will more efficient to handle.